# Hive UDAF for finding most frequently appearing column value

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a Hive UDAF to find most frequently appearing column (string) value (not single character or substring, exact column value is used) . Assume that the following is my table called my_table (dashes are used for separating columns visually).

```
User_Id - Item  - Count
 1  - A - 1
 1  - B - 1
 1  - A - 1
 1  - A - 1
 1  - A - 1
 1  - C - 1
 2  - C - 1
 2  - C - 1
 2  - A - 1
 2  - C - 1
```

Assume I call the following script :

```
Select User_Id, findFrequent(*) from my_table group by User_Id
```

I should be getting the following output because for User_Id=1, A appears 4 times and B and C appear only once. So, the most frequent one for User_Id=1 is A. Similarly, the most frequent one for User_Id=2 is C. In other words, each unique User_Id should have only one most frequent column value.

```
1 - A
2 - C
```

I created a class following this example https://github.com/rathboma/hive-extension-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/matthewrathbone/example/TotalNumOfLettersGenericUDAF.java but no luck so far. Here is my code:

```
@Description(name = "FindMostCommonString", value = "_FUNC_(expr) - Returns most commonly found string of a column.")
public class FindMostCommonString extends AbstractGenericUDAFResolver {

@Override
public GenericUDAFEvaluator getEvaluator(TypeInfo[] parameters)
        throws SemanticException {
    if (parameters.length != 1) {
        throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(parameters.length - 1,
                "Exactly one argument is expected.");
    }

    ObjectInspector oi = TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(parameters[0]);

    if (oi.getCategory() != ObjectInspector.Category.PRIMITIVE){
        throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0,
                        "Argument must be PRIMITIVE, but "
                        + oi.getCategory().name()
                        + " was passed.");
    }

    PrimitiveObjectInspector inputOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) oi;

    if (inputOI.getPrimitiveCategory() != PrimitiveObjectInspector.PrimitiveCategory.STRING){
        throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0,
                        "Argument must be String, but "
                        + inputOI.getPrimitiveCategory().name()
                        + " was passed.");
    }

    return new MostCommonStringEvaluator();
}

public static class MostCommonStringEvaluator extends GenericUDAFEvaluator {

    PrimitiveObjectInspector inputOI;
    ObjectInspector outputOI;
    MapObjectInspector mapOI;

    HashMap<String, Integer> total = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    @Override
    public ObjectInspector init(Mode m, ObjectInspector[] parameters)
            throws HiveException {

        assert (parameters.length == 1);
        super.init(m, parameters);

        // init input object inspectors

        if (m == Mode.PARTIAL1 || m == Mode.COMPLETE) {
            inputOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) parameters[0];
        }
        else{
            mapOI =  (MapObjectInspector) parameters[0];
        }

        outputOI = ObjectInspectorFactory.getReflectionObjectInspector(String.class,
                ObjectInspectorOptions.JAVA);


        return outputOI;

    }


    static class StringCountAgg implements AggregationBuffer {
        HashMap<String, Integer> strCount; 
        void add(String str){

            if(strCount.containsKey(str)){
                strCount.put(str,strCount.get(str)+1);
            }
            else{
                strCount.put(str,1);
            }
        }

        StringCountAgg(){
            strCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AggregationBuffer getNewAggregationBuffer() throws HiveException {
        StringCountAgg result = new StringCountAgg();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
        StringCountAgg myagg = new StringCountAgg();
    }

    private boolean warned = false;

    @Override
    public void iterate(AggregationBuffer agg, Object[] parameters)
            throws HiveException {
        assert (parameters.length == 1);
        if (parameters[0] != null) {
            StringCountAgg myagg = (StringCountAgg) agg;
            Object p1 = ((PrimitiveObjectInspector) inputOI).getPrimitiveJavaObject(parameters[0]);
            myagg.add((String)p1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object terminatePartial(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
        StringCountAgg myagg = (StringCountAgg) agg;
        appendToHashMap(total, myagg.strCount);
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public void merge(AggregationBuffer agg, Object partial)
            throws HiveException {
        if (partial != null) {

            StringCountAgg myagg1 = (StringCountAgg) agg;

            HashMap<String, Integer>  partialRes = (HashMap<String, Integer> ) mapOI.getMap(partial);

            appendToHashMap(myagg1.strCount, partialRes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object terminate(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
        StringCountAgg myagg = (StringCountAgg) agg;
        appendToHashMap(total, myagg.strCount);
        String result = null;
        int maxCount = 0;

        for(String key: total.keySet()){

            if(total.get(key) > maxCount){
                maxCount = total.get(key);
                result = key;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    private void appendToHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> main, HashMap<String, Integer> strCount) {
        for(String key: strCount.keySet()){
            if(main.containsKey(key)){
                main.put(key,main.get(key)+strCount.get(key));
            }
            else{
                main.put(key, strCount.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: did my query worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where are you stuck but I solved your problem using this approach:

***input:***

```
hive> Select * from test;
OK
1   A   1
1   B   1
1   A   1
1   A   1
1   A   1
1   C   1
2   C   1
2   C   1
2   A   1
2   C   1
Time taken: 0.15 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
```

***UPDATE: SQL Based solution:-***

```
select f1, f2 from ( 
select f1,f2,count(*) from test group by f1,f2 having count(*) in (
select max(total) as freq from (
select f1, f2, count(*) as total from test group by f1,f2) 
as test_temp group by f1)
) as final_results
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 9 seconds 700 msec
OK
1   A
2   C
Time taken: 75.901 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Update: Removed unrelated solutions for future reader(s)

Comment: thank you for your answer but the output doesn't seem to match with what I described in the question. Each unique User_Id is matched with one value. I am not interested in with third column at all.

Comment: thank you for updating your answer. I tried this query but it returns multiple matches for the same user id (first column). In fact, it returns all possible combinations for each `Item` (second column) values.

Comment: I am not sure, but see `select max(total)` - I am only fetching max `count(*)` per `userid` (f1), `item`(f1) - what you are saying ("returns multiple matches ") seems impossible. Note: I only tested with data as shown in my answer, and I got expected results. (I just ran the same query again)

Answer (score 1):

```
select User_Id,Item from HiveTable;
+---------+------+
| User_Id | Item |
+---------+------+
|       1 | A    |
|       1 | B    |
|       1 | A    |
|       1 | A    |
|       1 | A    |
|       1 | C    |
|       2 | C    |
|       2 | C    |
|       2 | C    |
|       2 | A    |
|       2 | C    |
+---------+------+
```

query-

```
select User_Id, Item from 
(
select User_Id,count(*) as total,Item from HiveTable group by User_Id, Item order by total desc
)q3 group by User_Id;
```

Output

```
+---------+------+
| User_Id | Item |
+---------+------+
|       1 | A    |
|       2 | C    |
+---------+------+
```

hope this will helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would be glad if you could explain query part. I am getting semantic error. I kinda get the subquery but I do not understand `q3 group by User_Id;` or having `Item` in outer query but not in `group by` statement at the end.

Comment: @Hamdi - I was in assumption that your are looking for `UDAF` specific solution (may be for your learning) but see my updated answer for pure `SQL` based solution.

Comment: @Kishore Kumar Suthar - I am definitely interested in your solution. Regarding your query: (1) I didn't understand your query. (2) most importantly the query fails in my hive. You have a group by statement at the end, which does not have `Item` in it. But you use Item directly in `select` statement at the beginning.